# deploying azure function app via Azure DevOps - how is the app service and storage provisioned?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-functions

I need to deploy an azure function app via Azure DevOps.
If I deploy via visual studio, it asks me to create a publish profile, where storage is specified.

I'm unsure how this works however with DevOps.
I have a build pipeline that builds the (.net core) function app, but on the release, I'm unsure how to proceed.

The Microsoft documentation is quite poor in my opinion, so would appreciate any expertise.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You have to create the underlying infrastructure prior to deploying the Azure Function to it.

There are steps you could user here and have an inline script job/stage within your pipeline:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/create-first-function-cli-csharp?tabs=azure-cli%2Cin-process#create-supporting-azure-resources-for-your-function

Alternatively you could use an ARM template or terraform to provision the app service and storage account as required.

I've got a sample github actions deployment of a function which uses the inline script method here:

https://github.com/brettmillerb/testfunctionapp/blob/master/.github/workflows/main.yml